# Prove that no function $f: \mathbb{N} \to (0,1)$ is surjective.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

To prove this can I proceed by contradiction and say, assume that $f: \mathbb{N} \to (0,1)$ is surjective, this would imply that $f(\mathbb{N})$ is equinumerous to $(0,1)$, but since $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, and $(0,1)$ is uncountable then they cannot be equinumerous and thus a contradiction, therefore $f: \mathbb{N} \to (0,1)$ is NOT surjective.

What are some other ways if this is correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say it quite implied equinumerousness, but it would make $(0, 1)$, by definition, countable.

Comment: The diagonal argument is an alternative (list $f(1),f(2),\ldots$ as decimals then find a number in $(0,1)$ which differs from $f(n)$ at least in the $n$th decimal place, carefully avoiding the double decimal representation of some numbers)

Comment: @Henry is this cantors diagnol argument?

Comment: Some people call it that, but what Cantor actually wrote in *[Uber ein elementare Frage der Mannigfaltigkeitslehre](http://www.logicmuseum.com/cantor/diagarg.htm)* did not consider $(0,1)$ or decimals, but instead considered $\mathbb N \to \{m,w\}^{\mathbb N}$